# Proof by induction $n^2 \geq n+1 \ \forall n \geq2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I have to prove by induction that $n^2 \geq n+1 \ \forall n \geq2$. I have done the following reasoning:

- the base case is easy to verify;
- supposing that $n^2 \geq n+1 $ is true, we prove $(n+1)^2 \geq n+1 +1$. That is $(n+1)^2 \geq n+1 +1 \implies n^2+2n+1 \geq n+2 \implies n^2 +2n \geq n+1$.

Now, should I conclude with "because we have assumed $n^2>n+1$, then it is possible to say that  $n^2 +2n \geq n+1$", or there are other steps to do to make the proof perfect?

Also, since this is my first proof, can you rewrite it in the most accepted and smooth way?

Comment: I find your proof very confusing. The term 'that is' is supposed to be used between equivalent statements and you're not doing that. Furthermore your $\implies$'s though true, do not help. What matters is the other direction, that is, what matters is $n^2\ge n+1\implies n^2+2n\ge n+1\implies (n+1)^2\ge (n+1)+1$.

Comment: This doesn't address your question, but is interesting so I am posting it as a comment. It's easy to see intuitively why this is true. Compare the expressions $$n^2 = n + \underbrace{n+n+\cdots+n}_{n-1\textrm{ addends}}$$ and $$n+1=n+\underbrace{1+0+0+\cdots+0}_{n-1\textrm{ addends}}$$ For $n\geq 2$, each of the indicated $n-1$ addends (which are all $n$, so at least $2$) in the first expression are strictly greater than the corresponding addends (which are all either $1$ or $0$) in the second expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would conclude with something like : "If the case holds true for some $n \ge 2$, then we have shown it is necessary that the case for $n + 1$ must also be true. Since the case for $n = 2$ is true, then by the principle of Mathematical Induction, we conclude that the proposition is true $\forall n \ge 2$."

Always think about the domino of induction when doing induction!

---

Here's how I would write a close to complete complete answer:

Let $P_n$ denote the proposition : $n^2 \ge n + 1 \quad\forall n \ge 2$. One can trivially show that $P_2$ is true.

Let $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+, k \ge 2$. Assume that $P_k$ is true. Then for $P_{k + 1}$,

$$\begin{align}(k + 1)^2 &= k^2 + 2k + 1\\
&\ge (k + 1) + 2k + 1\\
&= 3k + 2\\
&\ge (k + 1) + 1\end{align}$$

Since $P_2$ true and $P_{k + 1}$ is true whenever $P_k$ is true, then by the principle of Mathematical Induction, it follows that $P_n$ is true $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+, n \ge 2$.

Comment: You should say: Let $P_n$ be a "formula" with free variable $n$... A formula becomes a proposition if all of its free variables are replaced by constants or are quantified by quantifiers "for all" or "there exists".

Answer (score 1):

If $n^2\ge n+1,$

$(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1\ge (n+1)+2n+1$ (By inductive Hypothesis)

It is sufficient to show $3n+2\ge (n+1)+1$ which is true $\iff n\ge0$(We already have $n\ge2$)